# How to convert this select option into a list item changing states in react

Tags: reactjs, list, select, react-hooks, drop-down-menu

I want to convert this select option

```
const [Order, setOrder] = useState('');

if (Order === "Default") getVideoGame();
if (Order === "A-Z") Name_OrderA();
else if (Order === "Z-A") Name_OrderZ();
else if (Order === "Most Rated") Game_Rtn_Max();
else if (Order === "Least Rated") Game_Rtn_Min();
```

```
<select className="order__filter"
        onChange={(event) => setOrder(event.target.value)}>
  <option value="Default">Defecto</option>
  <option value="A-Z">Alphabetic A-Z</option>
  <option value="Z-A">Alphabetic Z-A</option>
  <option value="Most Rated">Most Rated</option>
  <option value="Least Rated">Least Rated</option>
</select>
```

I want to convert it into a dropdown menu like this, but with applying change state and displaying the list through a check:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" class="order__filter">
  <label for="check" class="order__label"> 
    <ul onChange={(event) => setOrder(event.target.value)}>
      <li>Alphabetic A-Z</li>
      <li>Alphabetic Z-A</li>
      <li>Most Rated</li>
      <li>Least Rated</li>
    </ul>
  </label>
</input>
```

I put the the select option into `li`, but the change of the state is not reflected. Also, it's to have more customizable options to edit the options of the dropdown, as select element is very limited. The check is to when select, show the dropdown menu.

I appreciate the help and any feedback, and if more info are need from my part. Thanks in advance.

I tried just replacing the select option with the unorder list item but didn't have results. I saw steps to click on the option of the dropdown menu to be redirected to another page but not to change status

Comment: Please use switch... case , instead of using multiple if .... then...